# Javascript and PHP Date issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

im using a JQuery calender and trying to save the date into the database, but on the response nothing shows.

If i alert the it on the Javascript side its there but not on the PHP server side.
I can echo the other data but not date.

```
function create(id,fname,lname,Date) {

alert(Date);
console.log(Date);
    //giving var's key names for the array
    var array1={id:id,
        firstname:fname,
        lastname:lname,
        date:Date}; 

    alert(array1);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?= B_SITE_URL; ?>/clinic/booking/UpdateCalender',
        timeout: 100000,
        data: array1, 
        cache: false,

        success: function (response) {
             alert("Sent Data"+response);
            }
    });
}
```

and this is the date format.

```
var startDateObj = new Date(parseInt(startYear), parseInt(startMonth) - 1,         
                                      parseInt(startDay), startHour, startMin, 0, 0);
```

and this is my php function

```
function actionUpdateCalender(){
echo "<pre>";
if (isset ($_POST)){

    echo $id =$_POST['firstname'];
     echo $day =$_POST['date'];
}

echo "</pre>";

self::setView(false);

}
```

Comment: Try changing the post field name `date` with something else like `user_date`.

Comment: ^ To elaborate on that point: Look at the syntax highlighting above. `Date` capitalized like that is reserved because its the name of the `Date` class. Its also not the "post field name" that needs to be changed but the Javascript variable name in your `create()` function.

Comment: Thanks, ive changed the Var to userdate instead but, the response i get is 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: nothing wrong with using `date` as an object property name

Comment: Thanks guys, i fixed the issue by using  userdate.toLocaleString() in the array.

Comment: Don't be shy to answer the question yourself and accept the answer, so others can find out easier how you solved your issue.

Comment: So naturally you debugged the issue, analysed the data on the wire, and discovered whether it's a JavaScript or a PHP problem then _entirely abstracted the non-problematic technology away_, right?

Comment: Yea it was a Javascript problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the Var to userdate and then used .toLocaleString
. it now echo's out the date, which i have to insert into the DB.

```
function create(id,fname,lname,userdate) {

alert(userdate);
console.log(userdate);

    //giving var's key names for the array
    var array1={id:id,
        firstname:fname,
        lastname:lname,
        userdate:userdate.toLocaleString()}; 


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?= B_SITE_URL; ?>/clinic/booking/UpdateCalender',
        timeout: 100000,
        data: array1, 
        cache: false,

        success: function (response) {
             alert("Sent Data"+response);


            }

    });
}
```